# JQuery .on("keydown") Not Working When Appended To Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a side menu of which you can right-click and choose to rename. This removed the `<a href="...` from the `<li></li>` and adds an input field. I cannot seem to have this appended input do anything however it seems I can get this to work on inputs of which have not been appended.

```js
$('.ShowInput').click(function(e) {
    $('body').html("<input type='text' value='search' class='search'>");
});
$("input").on("keydown",function search(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ShowInput">
  Click to show input
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I am not sure what you are asking, do you only want to keep the <a href="..."?

Comment: @shell I want to fire an event on enter of the appended `<input>` field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try binding your keydown event to an ancestor element, and pass your input with the search class as an argument to the `.on()` method.

```
$("body").on("keydown", "input.search", function (e) {
  var inputValue = $(this).val(); 
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert(inputValue);
  }
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Use following way to bind events for dynamically added elements.
Reference: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

```
$('document').on('keydown', '.search', function() {
   if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: $(document).on('keydown', '.search', function() {
   if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});